# Is it alright to promote a site proposal through the relevant Tag wikis?

Tags: discussion

The [Arduino site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49538/arduino) would interest a lot of the users of this site, so is it alright to promote it through the relevant tag wiki(s) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We heavily support arduino on site, previously this has resulted in the arduino site being closed as a duplicate.

I see no issue in the more detailed tag wiki linking to a proposed site, but I would not guarantee you are getting a site either.

Comment: I still don't see why we should have an apart arduino site. More sites doesn't always clarify things.